# zookeeper c binding installation on windows

Tags: installation, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to install zookeeper c binding on windows using cygwin

I get following error

```
Creating library file: .libs/libzookeeper_st.dll.a
./.libs/libzkst.a(zk_hashtable.o): In function `collectWatchers':
/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.3/src/c/src/zk_hashtable.c:285: undefined reference to `__imp__ZOO_SESSION_EVENT'
./.libs/libzkst.a(zk_hashtable.o): In function `do_foreach_watcher':
/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.3/src/c/src/zk_hashtable.c:273: undefined reference to `__imp__ZOO_SESSION_EVENT'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:567: recipe for target `libzookeeper_st.la' failed
make: *** [libzookeeper_st.la] Error 1
```

It compiled fine under linux CentOS

Answer (score 0):

This probably comes far too late. I had the exact same problem, and it is still present as of Zookeeper 3.4.5. Furthermore, the provided scripts fail to properly terminate Java.exe when launched using newer versions of the JRE.

NOTE: You'll need to install awk for the following solution to work. After you've done so, you can make the following changes to be able to compile and run properly through bash scripts:

1. Inside the file zookeeper-3.4.x/src/c/src/zk_hashtable.c, replace all instances of ZOO_SESSION_EVENT with SESSION_EVENT_DEF. These definitions are equivalent if you look through the source, and changing them will allow you to make properly. You can now compile regularly with "make".
2. If you have a recent version of Java, the scripts provided with Zookeeper in the bin directory (for example, zkServer.sh) will not properly kill Java. In fact, the JRE fails to respond to any SIGINT / SIGKILL etcetera signals passed to it from Cygwin. To solve this, you can change the following in zookeeper-3.4.x/bin/zkServer.sh:

   ```
   ZOOCFG=`cygpath -wp "$ZOOCFG"`
   # cygwin has a "kill" in the shell itself, gets confused
   KILL=/bin/kill
   ```

   Replace this with the following, to force the use of Windows taskkill instead, which the JRE cannot ignore:

   ```
   ZOOCFG=`cygpath -wp "$ZOOCFG"`
   # cygwin has a "kill" in the shell itself, gets confused
   KILL="taskkill /F /PID"
   ```

   Furthermore, also remove the following lines:

   ```
   $KILL -9 $(cat "$ZOOPIDFILE")
   rm "$ZOOPIDFILE"
   echo STOPPED
   ```

   Replace them with this, to force the script to send taskkill the Windows PID and not the Cygwin PID of the created Java task:

   ```
   if $cygwin
   then
       CYGPID=$(cat "$ZOOPIDFILE")
       WINPID=$(ps | awk "/$CYGPID/ { print \$4 }")
       $KILL $WINPID
   else
       $KILL $(cat "$ZOOPIDFILE")
   fi
   rm "$ZOOPIDFILE"
   echo STOPPED
   ```

And you're done! Again, make sure you have awk installed if you're planning on using the fix in the second step.

[cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) [c](/questions/tagged/c) [zookeeper](/questions/tagged/zookeeper)